# run local php/database application on windows pc without wamp

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php/mysql applications which I designed, and the client doesn't want it to be online (installed on a webserver) or available on the internet, he wants his employees to use it on a local system.

I don't want them to go through the process of starting up wamp to access the program, is there a simple way to make php web programs run on a local windows pc? using mysql database?

Comment: Configure a local machine to run the WAMP server and change your application configuration to point to this server instead of localhost.

Make sure your clients are on the same network as the server.

Comment: Shouldnt he have told you this important detail before you started working on the program???

Answer (score 2):

Wamp is definitely the way to go. You don't need to make the server accessible from the internet. You can install the web application on a wamp setup on a local web server and make it visible to the local network only. No need to install the application on every user's machine.